# Eclipse: Call requires API level 11 on first line of source file

Tags: android, eclipse

In my Android project I get the following error:

> Call requires API level 11 (current min is 8): android.app.Activity#onCreateView

The error is flagged on the first line of the source file (which specifies the package name). If I clean the project, it disappears, but reappears semi-randomly as I edit the code.

Minimum API for the project is 8, target API is beyond 11.

What is causing this, and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

It is hard to say for sure without seeing the code in question but from your description it seems that your code might be overloading:

```
// Which was added on API 11.
View onCreateView (View parent, 
                String name, 
                Context context, 
                AttributeSet attrs)
```

If you need this call, wrap around it with an API check (keep in mind you might have improper behavior when running in API < 11 if you do). If not overload instead:

```
// Available since API 1
View onCreateView (String name, 
                Context context, 
                AttributeSet attrs)
```